# Is there an option a JTextField can check the input on a specific format?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I want to use a JTextField to enter dates in the YYYY-MM-DD format. Is there a possibility to validate the entered format?

Comment: See: [How to Use Formatted Text Fields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html). Keep a link to the Swing tutorial handy for all Swing basics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking about Input Validation. Do this yourself with an event listener that is triggered

- either whenever the field content changes,
- or when the field loses focus
- or when the dialog's ok button is pressed

Which mechanism you use depends on how quickly you want to give feedback and how costly a validation is.

As an alternative you can refer to the [Swing Frameworks Input Validation features](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html#inputVerification).